# How to use regular expressions in xPath in LibXML (Perl)?

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, libxml2, xpath-2.0

I need to search by attributes using a regular expression.

In Python it would look like this:

```
from lxml import etree

dom = etree.parse(r'/path/to/file.XML')

regexpNS = "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
els = dom.xpath("//*[(re:test(@NAME, '.*Town.*', 'i')) and (@ISACTIVE='1' )]", namespaces={'re':regexpNS})

el = els[0]

print(el.attrib['NAME'] +" => " + el.attrib['OBJECTGUID'])
```

I don't understand how to do it in perl

```
my $dom = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file("/path/to/file.XML");

my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($dom);
$xpc->registerNs('re', 'http://exslt.org/regular-expressions');
print $xpc->findnodes(q{//*[(re:test(@NAME, '.*Town.*', 'i')) and (@ISACTIVE='1' )]});
```

gives an error message

> error : xmlXPathCompOpEval: function test not found XPath error :
>
> Unregistered function at line ...

I tried to rewrite the well-known example:

Custom XPath functions

This example demonstrates registerFunction() method by defining a function filtering nodes based on a Perl regular expression:

```
sub grep_nodes { 
  my ($nodelist,$regexp) =  @_;
  my $result = XML::LibXML::NodeList->new;
  for my $node ($nodelist->get_nodelist()) {
    $result->push($node) if $node->textContent =~ $regexp;
  }
  return $result;
};

my $xc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($node);
$xc->registerFunction('grep_nodes', \&grep_nodes);
my @nodes = $xc->findnodes('//section[grep_nodes(para,"\bsearch(ing|es)?\b")]');
```

Rewrote it like this:

```
use XML::LibXML;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->new->parse_string(<<'EOT');
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ADDRESSOBJECTS>
  <OBJECT ID="1" NAME="Broadway" TYPENAME="st" LEVEL="8" ISACTIVE="1" />
  <OBJECT ID="2" NAME="Times Square" TYPENAME="sq" LEVEL="8" ISACTIVE="1" />
  <OBJECT ID="3" NAME="DownTown" TYPENAME="st" LEVEL="8" ISACTIVE="1" />
  <OBJECT ID="4" NAME="MidthTown" TYPENAME="st" LEVEL="8" ISACTIVE="1" />
  <OBJECT ID="5" NAME="UpTown" TYPENAME="st" LEVEL="8" ISACTIVE="1" />
</ADDRESSOBJECTS>
EOT


sub grep_attrs {
  my ($nodelist,$attr_name,$regexp) =  @_;
  my $result = XML::LibXML::NodeList->new;
  for my $node ($nodelist->get_nodelist()) {
    my %attrs = map { $_->getName => $_->getValue } $node->attributes;
    $result->push($node) if $attrs{$attr_name} =~ $regexp;
    print $attrs{$attr_name}."\n" if $attrs{$attr_name} =~ $regexp;
  }
  return $result;
};

print "\n-========================================-\n";

my $xc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($dom);
$xc->registerFunction('grep_attrs', \&grep_attrs);
my @nodes = $xc->findnodes(q{//*[grep_attrs(OBJECT,'NAME','.*Town.*')]});

print "\n-========================================-\n";
print @nodes;
print "\n-========================================-\n";
```

output result:

```
-========================================-
DownTown
MidthTown
UpTown

-========================================-
<ADDRESSOBJECTS>
  <OBJECT ID="1" NAME="Broadway" TYPENAME="st" LEVEL="8" ISACTIVE="1"/>
  <OBJECT ID="2" NAME="Times Square" TYPENAME="sq" LEVEL="8" ISACTIVE="1"/>
  <OBJECT ID="3" NAME="DownTown" TYPENAME="st" LEVEL="8" ISACTIVE="1"/>
  <OBJECT ID="4" NAME="MidthTown" TYPENAME="st" LEVEL="8" ISACTIVE="1"/>
  <OBJECT ID="5" NAME="UpTown" TYPENAME="st" LEVEL="8" ISACTIVE="1"/>
</ADDRESSOBJECTS>
-========================================-
```

function works, but!

1. too long, many times longer than in python
2. For some reason it returns the full tree, not the found nodes.

Help me understand the problem and how can use regular expressions when searching by attributes??

Comment: libxml2, the C library used by XML::LibXML, supports XPath 1, which doesn't have regex. `.*Town.*` can be achieved using `contains`, other than the the case-insensitivity.

Comment: And what to do? And, this is very strange because - lxml is a Pythonic, mature binding for the **libxml2** and libxslt libraries. It provides safe and convenient access to these libraries using the ElementTree API. And with lxml everything seems to work.

Comment: [See for yourself](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/-/wikis/home) ("Libxml2 implements a number of existing standards related to markup languages: [...] XML Path Language (XPath) 1.0 [...]")

Comment: @SergeyZakharov  "_very strange because - lxml is a Pythonic, mature binding for the libxml2 and libxslt libraries_ "  --- not relevant for this conversation whether it is "_Pythonic_" and/or "_mature_", but it seems clear that it isn't just a "_binding_" (for libxml2).  At any rate, as I wrote in a comment under Shawn's answer, you can simply use your working (and satisfactory for you) Python code.  There are many ways to use it out of Perl, including a simple library that you can write in minutes.

Comment: ikegami, We know, read... I was asking about registered functions that can be used by the XML::LibXML module. The solution was through them and it exists and works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using the XML::LibXML module and a registered function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -CSDA
use utf8;
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = <<'EOXML';
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ADDRESSOBJECTS>
  <OBJECT ID="1" NAME="Broadway" TYPENAME="st" LEVEL="8" ISACTIVE="1" />
  <OBJECT ID="2" NAME="Times Square" TYPENAME="sq" LEVEL="8" ISACTIVE="1" />
  <OBJECT ID="3" NAME="DownTown" TYPENAME="st" LEVEL="8" ISACTIVE="1" />
  <OBJECT ID="4" NAME="MidthTown" TYPENAME="st" LEVEL="8" ISACTIVE="1" />
  <OBJECT ID="5" NAME="UpTown" TYPENAME="st" LEVEL="8" ISACTIVE="1" />
</ADDRESSOBJECTS>
EOXML

my $dom = XML::LibXML->new->parse_string($xml);

sub xpath_matches {
  my ($input,$pattern,$flg) =  @_;
  $flg = '' if !defined ($flg);
  return 1 if $input =~ /(?$flg)$pattern/;
  return undef;
}

my $xc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($dom);
$xc->registerFunction('matches', \&xpath_matches);

say $_->getAttribute('NAME').' '.$_->getAttribute('TYPENAME')
  for $xc->findnodes(q{
    //OBJECT[@NAME and matches(@NAME,'.*[tT]oWn$','i')]
  });
```

PS: because there are no boolean values in perl, and matches is a function that returns some value, then its result must be compared with some value, in this case with 1, if only one function is used in the XPATH query, see example:

> ```
> //OBJECT[matches(@NAME,'.*[tT]oWn$','i')=1]
> ```

if there are some other operations in the XPATH query, then you can use it without comparison, as in the example above

> ```
> //OBJECT[@NAME and matches(@NAME,'.*[tT]oWn$','i')]
> ```

or

> ```
> //OBJECT[matches(@NAME,'.*[tT]oWn$','i') and 1]
> ```

This solution is almost 15 times faster than XML::XPath on very large XML files. And on files of hundreds of megabytes, XML::XPath just dies.

All was need to do it was write and use the registered function correctly.

So regular expressions in XPATH in XML::LibXML can be used!

Answer (score 4):

Using [`XML::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath) instead, which has support for regular expressions via the `matches()` XPath 2.0 function as of a few releases ago thanks to yours truly:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use XML::XPath v1.45;

my $xml = <<'EOXML';
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ADDRESSOBJECTS>
  <OBJECT ID="1" NAME="Broadway" TYPENAME="st" LEVEL="8" ISACTIVE="1" />
  <OBJECT ID="2" NAME="Times Square" TYPENAME="sq" LEVEL="8" ISACTIVE="1" />
  <OBJECT ID="3" NAME="DownTown" TYPENAME="st" LEVEL="8" ISACTIVE="1" />
  <OBJECT ID="4" NAME="MidthTown" TYPENAME="st" LEVEL="8" ISACTIVE="1" />
  <OBJECT ID="5" NAME="UpTown" TYPENAME="st" LEVEL="8" ISACTIVE="1" />
</ADDRESSOBJECTS>
EOXML

my $xp = XML::XPath->new(xml => $xml);

my @nodes = $xp->findnodes(q{//*[matches(@NAME, 'town', 'i') and @ISACTIVE = 1]});

for my $node (@nodes) {
  say $node->getAttribute('NAME');
}
```

prints out

```
DownTown
MidthTown
UpTown
```

Comment: Yes, it works! BUT, it works even slower than with the registered function in example above - 3.27 times slower and **21.7 times slower than the python** example on the 11Mb XML file. I'm afraid to imagine working with a 600MB file. And I need to simultaneously parse three files, one for 11MB and two files for 600MB.
The question is - why is the function behaving so strangely or how to rewrite it correctly? I replaced the array map with $node->getAttribute($attr_name), the speed **doubled**, it's very good, but the returned result is not clear, I'm at a loss, how to rewrite it?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you're doing with those hundreds of Mb so it's hard to compare speeds ... regardless, why don't you use your great Python library then?  If it must be done out of a Perl script for some other reasons you can write a short Python code for it and run that out of Perl.  Or, write a Perl module which does that and your main Perl script can then use that as a library.  That's precisely how libraries work (including that Python's one -- it uses other tools to do its thing).  You'll get the near exact performance as that Python code, which you say is so much faster.

Comment: It's a pure perl module instead of a wrapper around a C library so it's not surprising it's slower.

Comment: Another option might be to write some XSLT that outputs what you want from your documents and use a XSLT processor that doesn't depend on libxml2.

Comment: Shawn, I understand and agree with the C library for execution speed.  Regarding the use XSLT instead of XPATH  - hmm... there is no need to make all that fuss.

Comment: zdimm, I search for a node(s) by attributes. In this case, the attribute @NAME must be searched using RegEx. Using Python from Perl is still bad manners :) IMHO, it's also inconvenient, and wrapping it in a module, well, it's such a very strange thing to do... It's easier to write everything in Python right away. For myself, I found some temporary solution - using starts-with(), ends-with() and contains() in XPATH. This covers some of the needs, for now at least. But I'm still wondering how to use the registered function, how to write it correctly so that it works? And I did it, see my answer